# How to handle JSON data in POST request in C# (.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net, json, angular

Previously (In .Net Core 2.1) I successfully handled JSON data with below method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("sendJsonData")]
public JObject saveTemplate(JObject jsonString)
{

        string templateName = (string)jsonString.SelectToken("templateName");
        string filePathAndName = "D:\\" + "templates\\" + templateName + ".txt";

        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@filePathAndName))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(file, jsonString);
        }

    return jsonString;
}
```

But when I created the same method with .Net Core 3.1. It is not working showing some error with JObject.
I am getting that JSON from below code

```
onSubmit() {
this.http.post("https://localhost:44350/ReportAPI/sendJsonData", this.surveyForm.value)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log("success!", data),
                error => console.error("couldn't post because", error)
            );
}
```

Below is the error (Response from Postman)

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|6e209814-4dd7396cc2dfa182.",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 14."
        ]
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{  
   "templateName":"BFS Survey",
   "surveyQuestions":[  
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Name",
         "questionType":"Text",
         "questionGroup":{  

         }
      },
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Age",
         "questionType":"Number",
         "questionGroup":{  

         }
      },
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Gender",
         "questionType":"Single choice",
         "questionGroup":{  
            "options":[  
               {  
                  "optionText":"Male"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"Female"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"Other"
               }
            ],
            "showRemarksBox":false
         }
      },
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Skills",
         "questionType":"Multi choice",
         "questionGroup":{  
            "options":[  
               {  
                  "optionText":"Java"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"Angular"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"Python"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"R"
               }
            ],
            "showRemarksBox":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Code perfectly worked using .Net Core 2.1 but not working with 3.1. Please suggest me how resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post that error

Comment: I have so many questions about this implementation... can you show us the error? usually, a dedicated class is used to deserialize the json from the request body, instead of a plain JObject. Also, why are you catching an error just to throw it again? you could get rid of the entire try catch block, and it would act exactly the same

Comment: Please see updated question for error. @GlennvanAcker

Comment: Please see updated question for error. @Rajesh

Comment: @AbhiSharma can you debug the code, and show the json you are sending to your api? it can't deserialize it into an object.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker I have added JSON in question. Do you think that there is alternate option to handle that json instead of JObject?

Comment: @AbhiSharma Add in Startup.cs, in method `ConfigureServices`: `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();` Make sure you add a package reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

Comment: @RahulSharma It worked!!! Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @RahulSharma you can post your comment as answer so I can accept that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.x to 3.0, refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support):

- Add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`
- Add in Startup.cs, in method ConfigureServices: `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();`